# Outlook Add-in Embed Canvas app , Add-in is not displaying in Outlook

Tags: outlook-web-addins, powerapps-canvas, power-platform, dynamics365-app-outlook

Created canvas app and created Microsoft 365 subscription trail, I have followed the below URL for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iKAgJQiJZI . After hitting the start button, corresponding mailbox rendering in browser but while opening the message not able to see the add-in, am I missing any settings? any help is appreciated.

MessageRead.html - introduced iframe
MessageRead.js :- document ready loading the canvas app in I frame.

Addin should display in outlook but not as well as no error. am I missing any setting?